# Laravel - Passing data to email view

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5.1

I can not access the confirmation_code variable in my email.verify view by using this variable in my view:

```
$user->confirmation_code
```

Shouldn't this be accessible when I assigned the array items like this? What am I overlooking?

```
$user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'confirmation_code' => str_random(30)
        ]);

        Mail::send('emails.verify', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Email verificatie');
        });
```

All the other variables like, name, email, password are accessible and I am giving the mail send method my user object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add `'confirmation_code'` to the array `$fillable` in the User.php file?

Comment: Damn. I found out this was the case indeed. But I am wondering how come you sometimes get a mass assignment exception error but in this case it didn't give any error?

Comment: @Stephan-v I think mass assignment exception error comes when you're trying to create the new model object.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your are not passing your `confirmation_code` to the email template. Just save `confirmation code` to some variable

```
 Mail::send('emails.verify', ['user' => $user, 'confirmation_code' => $yourConfirmationCodevariable ], function($m){
                        $$m->to($user->email)->subject('Transaction Details');
                    });
```

And in your `verify.blade`

just do `{{ $confirmation_code }}`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables in Mailable views, by doing this:

```
...

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.viewname')->with(['explicit_variable' => $some_value]);
}

...
```